# Filter out Facebook Contacts from the Contact Picker

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have a contact picker in my application that keeps crashing when a facebook contact is selected. I won't have the code I'm using to open the picker in front of me, but I believe I'm accessing the contacts through a call similar to this:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI)
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

i wish i had an answer for you but i posted 2 similar questions without any good answers.  seems like a totally reasonable question and easy to do in most other dev environments (im actually a c# developer) but android has got me stuck on this.  i think i may just have to write my "own contact picker" so that i can test for the fact that the contact has a number before adding them to the picker list programmatically.

anyways, my questions are here:

[How do get the android sdk contact picker to give me just phone results and not all my twitter followers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332846/how-do-get-the-android-sdk-contact-picker-to-give-me-just-phone-results-and-not)

[how do i get startActivityForResult() to bring up just a list of telephone contacts (like when i click on the "People" icon) using the android sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705248/how-do-i-get-startactivityforresult-to-bring-up-just-a-list-of-telephone-conta)

in my app i am testing that the phone gets returned from the picked contact before trying to send it a message (so mine doesnt crash), but i dont want the user to have to see a "that contact doesnt have a number" message if they dont have to.

i found this too:
http://mobile.dzone.com/news/contacts-api-20-and-above

while it DOESNT show you how to filter the contact list, it does show how to programmatically create a list that has only contacts with numbers.  write back on my questions if you find anything that could be useful, thanks!

Comment: I actually fixed this by re-doing the contact picker to use similar code to this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BusinessCard/index.html That's as good as I could get to keep it from crashing looking for contact data. Otherwise you basically have to override everything and filter the list yourself =) good luck if you are still working on it!